# Ways of Pyspark tabular data manipulation

Tags: pyspark

I'm very new to pyspark and I'm kind of confused with the data manipulation. What I learned lately is that we can manipulate data (tabular data) with SQL queries or with pyspark dataframes built in methods. My question is

1. Is there another way to manipulate tabular data in pyspark other than with SQL queries or with pyspark dataframes built in methods?
2. Why some people manipulate the data with SQL and some others with the built in methods? I mean it's mentioned that spark dataframes can act like SQL table, so why using the built in functions?
3. In the best practice, when to manipulate the data with SQL queries and with pyspark dataframes built in methods?

I'm sorry if this is a basic question but I'm very new at this and I have been looking for articles to answer the questions I have but to no avail.

Comment: This is more of a organizational / project specific choice. In my opinion people who comes from SQL background feels excitement  in writing   spark-sql code , however a modern or easy approach is Dataframe , in case there is complex business logic needs to be catered - dataset or RDD can be used. More of a personal choice, the whole idea is to solve problem using analytical skill. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ah I see, so it's just a matter of preference? not because "this one works faster, more efficient, using less memory, etc"?

Comment: strictly preference. I prefer the chaining methods approach for easier readability then just a blob of sql text.